# Why issue only 1 AJAX call return 2 GET request knockout and jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, get, jsreport

I am having setup like this:
Knockout binding between views/people and viewsModel/people.js
A button to call AJAX to jsreport server to print PDF
Button in views/people

```
<button id="printPdf"
data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton}">
</button>
```

In viewsModel/people.js, an click event call to jsreport server

```
self.someotherstuff = ko.pureComputed(function () {
......
//print button
self.print = $("#printPdf").click(function () {
$.getJSON(
//some logic
).then(function (){jsreport.serverUrl = 'http://localhost:5488';
var request = {
template: { 
"shortid":"rJPUhdmv"
 }};
 jsreport.render('_blank', request);       
 })
....
}
```

But why there is always 2 GET request received instead of 1?
EDIT:
The whole print button is inside an purecomputed like above

Comment: You've probably attached your event listener twice. If you're using knockout, it's better to use the `click` binding instead of jquery to make your UI interactive...

Comment: It is out of scope for this question, but to tell the truth, I am stuck when trying to invoke a click event by knockout. It just... does not recognize the bidding somehow (I have shallow understanding of KO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ko.computed` or `ko.pureComputed` is re-evaluated every time one of its dependencies changes. This means you **should not attach event listeners inside a `pureComputed`'s method**.

Also note that a `pureComputed` by definition should not have any side effects. Take this example:

```js
var counter = 0;
var dependency = ko.observable("A");

var myComputed = ko.computed(function() {
  counter += 1;
  return dependency() + "-computed";
});

dependency("B");
dependency("C");

console.log(counter); // Logs 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, `myComputed` was evaluated three times.

1. At the time of its initialization (output: `A-computed`)
2. When `dependency` was updated to `B` (output: `B-computed`)
3. When `dependency` was updated to `C` (output: `C-computed`)

You should create an `onClick` method in your viewmodel, and bind it using `data-bind="click: onClick"`:

```
self.onClick = function(data, event) {
  // Ajax stuff...
}
```

And:

```
<button id="printPdf"
  data-bind="click: onClick, ojComponent: {component: ojButton}">
</button>
```

You didn't show your custom `ojComponent` binding, so I can't say for sure if it conflicts with the `click` binding...

Comment: Are you the guy who turned water into wine some time ago? Thank you so so much) :)